# Can we add dynamic hair particles to a softbody simulation?

Tags: particles, physics, hair, soft-body

I am modeling a winter Cap, The model looks like this
[image]

I am trying to apply softbody physics to the fur ball on the top of the cap. The physics act properly on the ball but the hair particles don't animate. I had the hair dynamics enabled.

Video Link is down below which will help you guys understand What I am speaking about : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UPyN2jaw88UCiHXp6p47w4Tku5rzhFrr/view?usp=sharing

My question is can we have dynamic hair particles on the soft body physics object? if yes, how do we do it?

by the way, I am using blender 2.8 for this.

thanks

Comment: just checked it in 2.76. it works there.

Comment: ensure your particles modifier are next to the softbody (below) in the modifiers stack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think its a bug with blender 2.8 then, because it also works with 2.79 too.